# Polling based action on spark streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

In general in spark stream one can do transformations (filter, map, etc.) or output operations (`collect`, `forEach`, etc) in an event-driven pardigm (i.e. the action happens only if a message is received).

Is it possible to do actions every few seconds in a polling based fashion, regardless if a new message has been received?

In my use-case, I am filtering out a stream, and then do operations on this filtered stream. However, I would like to do operations on the data in the stream every few seconds even if no message has been received in the stream.

For example I have the following stream, where the `violationChecking()` function is being called only when a micro-batch is finished. Essentially this also means that I must receive a message in this stream to do processing. Is there any way that I can do the same operation every 10 seconds?

```
sortedMessages.foreach(
    new Function<JavaRDD<Tuple5<Long, Integer, String, Integer, Integer>>, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call(JavaRDD<Tuple5<Long, Integer, String, Integer, Integer>> tuple5JavaRDD) throws Exception {
         List<Tuple5<Long, Integer, String, Integer, Integer>> list = tuple5JavaRDD.collect();
         violationChecking(list);
         return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please see the update and let me know if it makes the question clearer.

Comment: I can't help you, but I think the question is clearer now.